# Avoid overlapping curves in Corel draw

Tags: vba, coreldraw

I have a lot of circles (curves) in my Corel draw file and I am looking for a way to automatically delete curves that are overlapped. Is there any script or other way to do this?

Comment: When you say "delete curves that are overlapped", do you mean delete both such curves? Then, have the circles in discussion already been converted to curves? Did you try something on your own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code removes only the overlapping shapes being on top:

```
Sub RemoveOverlappedShapesBis()
 Dim sh As Shape, s As Shape, sR As Shape, shR As ShapeRange, d As Document, shrR As New ShapeRange, i As Long
 
 Set d = ActiveDocument
 Set shR = d.ActiveLayer.Shapes.All
 For Each sh In shR.Shapes
    For Each s In shR.Shapes
       If shR.IndexOf(sh) <> shR.IndexOf(s) Then
            If sh.DisplayCurve.IntersectsWith(s.DisplayCurve) Then
                If s.ZOrder > sh.ZOrder Then
                    If shrR.Count > 0 Then
                        For Each sR In shrR.Shapes
                             If shrR.IndexOf(s) = 0 Then
                                shrR.Add s: Exit For
                            End If
                        Next
                    Else
                        shrR.Add s
                    End If
                End If
            End If
       End If
    Next
 Next
 shrR.Shapes.All.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I mean removing only the overlapping shape and the second code worked for me.

Comment: @elyasbn : Glad I could help! I will delete the first variant, then...